# Can you add Schema.org/JobPosting support to Stack Overflow Jobs

Tags: feature-request, status-planned, stack-overflow-jobs

Can you add Schema.org JobPosting support to job offers on Stack Overflow Jobs?

Schema.org is a joint initiative by search engines (Google, Yahoo, Yandex…)

It's semantic markup that makes the jobs discoverable by search engines (it's basically free SEO for job postings) and more accessible (for screen readers…).

The standard open markup is simple to implement and available at: [schema.org/JobPosting](http://schema.org/JobPosting)

Answer (score 2):

We'll be doing a bunch of SEO work very soon, we'll definitely be investigating this, thanks!